# how to do table calculations and iterations with javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, html-table, calc

**Background:**
I'm trying to learn javascript, so I decided to try to make a spreadsheet-like thing to learn the loopings. Now I've been working with this on and off for over a month, and I could really use some extra help. Since I'm trying to learn vanilla js, I'm trying to stay out of anything else than that.

**So far:**
I have found different solutions both for calculating the rows and a whole table, but I don't feel that any of these solutions are very good. Mainly I've been using for-loops for this, but it has come to my attention that foreach might be better, and I am trying to learn... So right now I'm trying to understand nested foreach loops.

**Problem:**
Since I'm going to use the data from each cell on different places in my tables, I will need to figure out how to separate each row from the rest of the rows and then separate each cell in that specific row (for calculating columns).

**Solutions:**
As I said, I have some weird solutions for calculating rows, and even a whole table, but they don't really answer my problem. One thought, I might be very wrong here, is to, somehow, make every row to an array.
I know that similar questions has been asked here before, and I've tested several of them, but I'm still stuck.

I have put all code in the fiddlejs below. The table is set to work onchange.

Any kind of help is much appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/mpv0ds5g/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- FORM 1 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <caption>
            <strong>FIRST</strong>
          </caption>
          <tbody>
            <!-- ROW 0 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 0</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 1 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 1</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 2 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <caption>
            <strong>SECOND</strong>
          </caption>
          <tbody>
            <!-- ROW 2 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 2</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 3 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 3</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 4 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 3</th>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 3 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <caption>
            <strong>THIRD</strong>
          </caption>
          <tbody>
            <!-- ROW 4 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 4</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 5 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 5</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 4 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <caption>
            <strong>FOURTH</strong>
          </caption>
          <tbody>
            <!-- ROW 6 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 6</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><output></output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 7 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 7</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output></output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 8 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 8</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output></output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 9 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 9</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output></output></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 5 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <caption>
            <strong>FIFTH</strong>
          </caption>
          <tbody>
            <!-- ROW 10 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 10</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 11 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 11</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 12 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 12</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 13 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 13</th>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ROW 14 -->
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 14</th>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
              <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

forms.forEach(() => {
  f0 = forms[0];
  f1 = forms[1];
  f2 = forms[2];
  f3 = forms[3];
  f4 = forms[4];

  f0.onchange = editSheet;
  f1.onchange = editSheet;
  f2.onchange = editSheet;
  f3.onchange = editSheet;
  f4.onchange = editSheet;
});

function editSheet() {
  const body = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
  const allrows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
  const input = document.querySelectorAll("input");


// unwanted for-loop. Gets the job done, but returns html-error in the console
  for (i = 0; i < allrows.length; i++) {
    rowTotal = 0;
    for (ii = 0; ii < allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input").length; ii++) {
      rowTotal =
        rowTotal + Number(allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[ii].value);
    }
    allrows[i].querySelector(".rowsum").innerHTML = rowTotal;
  }

  /*
  body.forEach(() => {
    console.log(body[0]);
  }); // gives every <tbody>
  */

  /*
  allrows.forEach((i, ix) => {
    console.log(ix, i);
  }); // gives every <tr>
*/
  /*
  input.forEach((i, ix) => {
    console.log(ix, i.value);
  }); // gives every value in the cells
  */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some table fundamentals...

Tables have the reserved words "**rows**" and "**cells**" to make life easier.

The content of a cell is accessible via...

```
T.rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML
```

Therefore, to get the value of [row 6 , cell 4] we go...

```
var value = T.rows[6].cells[4].innerHTML; // "T" being the ID of the table.
```

To loop through a table we go...

```
for(var x=0; x<T.rows.length; x++){

  T.rows[x].cells[3].innerHTML=5; // set the 3rd cell of every row to 5
}
```

Now the nested loop to go through every cell...

```
for(var x=0; x<T.rows.length; x++){

 for(var y=0; y<T.cells.length; y++){

  T.rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML=0; // Initialise all cells with zero.

 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I haven't tried it yet, but I guess this will enable both calculating columns as well as using the number in other places, for example, add row 0 and 1 and display the sum in row 7?

Comment: A very nice thing with this is that you can target each cell. This will be great for the lower tables. cells.length gives an error though: "app.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

The fourth table has no element with the `rowsum` class. This causes the error because `allrows[i].querySelector(".rowsum")` returns `null`. In turn, this is because there are no `rowsum` elements to return.

As for the loop itself, the `for` loop can be replaced with a `.forEach` call.

Comment: Aaaaah, awesome info. I'll have a look at that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: A great tip to get rid of that error message. Thanks. The forEach loops are coming around, still a bit tricky with the nested ones though, and still working on adding the columns :-/

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a little bit differently. Instead of looping through every single row in every single form, I would detect—with `event.target`—which input that was changed, and then "traverse up" through the DOM to the parent `<tr>` (via `parentElement`) and querySelect from that element.

I think the code is self explanatory. I added a few extra variables in `editSheet()` to make it more apparent what's going on.

I also changed your `forEach` loop so it's a little bit dynamic (add or remove forms without having to update the code) and with less code.

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

forms.forEach((formElement) => {
  formElement.onchange = editSheet;

/*  f0 = forms[0];
  f1 = forms[1];
  f2 = forms[2];
  f3 = forms[3];
  f4 = forms[4];

  f0.onchange = editSheet;
  f1.onchange = editSheet;
  f2.onchange = editSheet;
  f3.onchange = editSheet;
  f4.onchange = editSheet;*/
});

function editSheet(event) {
  const inputElement     = event.target;  // the input that sent the event
  const tableCellElement = inputElement.parentElement;      // td
  const tableRowElement  = tableCellElement.parentElement;  // tr
  
  const tableCellElements = tableRowElement.querySelectorAll('input');
  const outputElement     = tableRowElement.querySelector('output');
  
  let totalSum = 0;
  const DEFAULT_ZERO = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < tableCellElements.length; i++) {
    totalSum += Number(tableCellElements[i].value) || DEFAULT_ZERO;
  }

  outputElement.value = totalSum;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- FORM 1 -->
  <form>
    <table>
      <caption>
        <strong>FIRST</strong>
      </caption>
      <tbody>
        <!-- ROW 0 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 0</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 1 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 1</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <!-- FORM 2 -->
  <form>
    <table>
      <caption>
        <strong>SECOND</strong>
      </caption>
      <tbody>
        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 2</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 3</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 4 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 3</th>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <!-- FORM 3 -->
  <form>
    <table>
      <caption>
        <strong>THIRD</strong>
      </caption>
      <tbody>
        <!-- ROW 4 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 4</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 5 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 5</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <!-- FORM 4 -->
  <form>
    <table>
      <caption>
        <strong>FOURTH</strong>
      </caption>
      <tbody>
        <!-- ROW 6 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 6</th>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
          <td><output></output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 7 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 7</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output></output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 8 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 8</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output></output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 9 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 9</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output></output></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <!-- FORM 5 -->
  <form>
    <table>
      <caption>
        <strong>FIFTH</strong>
      </caption>
      <tbody>
        <!-- ROW 10 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 10</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 11 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 11</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 12 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 12</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 13 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 13</th>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="editTable output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ROW 14 -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Row 14</th>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="colsum output">0</output></td>
          <td><output class="rowsum output">0</output></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: So great. I really thought there should be a more efficient way to do this. Great idea regarding the event.target. I will absolutely look in to that. Thank you very very much.

Comment: This is an awesome solution for calculating the rows. I'm having a harder time with the columns :( And I'm not really sure (haven't come to that part yet), how to move the inputs further down the sheet. For example, if I want to add the first cell in the first row with the first cell in the second row and output it in the first cell in row 9.

Comment: OK, so that's why you got so many outputs in the later rows. I guess you need to build a complex data structure for that, which is simple but tons of work. If you're just learning javascript, that's not really the project you should be doing, especially when there are frameworks like React, Angular, Polymer and Vue that can do that without any trouble, as that functionality is a tiny feature within the frameworks.

Comment: Aaahh, I see. Yeah, it's quite a challenge for me, haha. Thanks a ton for your answer, that actually helps more than you think :)